# Converting Particles Into Fluid

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I wanted to ask if there is a way to convert a particle system to a fluid?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called **Cube-Surfer** that can do that. It voxels your particles and creates a mesh-skin around them.

Take a look: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz2VivdcfQs

Download: 
http://pyroevil.com/cubesurfer-addon-download/

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it worked for you.

Comment: please how do I do that Ben?

Comment: and I also don't know how to convert the script into an addon

Comment: It is an add-on. My guess is, you did not install it properly. 
To select an answer as accepted, set the check-mark next to the vote count. Take the tour, it has a guide: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hey, to mark an answer as accepted, just click the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pyroevil add-on does it, but the company's official site is down. 
This is up right now:

https://github.com/Pyroevil/CubeSurfer

Go there and download the add-on.